# my application crashes when i create a class instance of a new class in my mainactivity

Tags: android

```
public class main_activity extends Activity implementsBluetoothLeUart.Callback{

Activity activity;
DisplayMetrics metrics;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String> liste,devicedata;
private ListView list;
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
public EditText input;
String name,address,Devicename,Deviceaddress,datadevicename;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
public static String SelectedDeviceName;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
public boolean mScanning;
public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> dev;
private Handler mHandler;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
SqlHandler sh = new SqlHandler(this);
//BluetoothLeService service = new BluetoothLeService();
BluetoothLeUart uart = new BluetoothLeUart(this);//this is where i am creating the instance
public static BluetoothDevice device;
private BluetoothGatt mGatt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);


    activity = this;

    mHandler = new Handler();
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    scanLeDevice(true);
    mActionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#727272'>Board List</font>"));
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    liste = new ArrayList<String>();
    liste.clear();
    sh.openDB();
    Cursor cur = sh.getAllnames();
    while(cur.moveToNext()){
         name = cur.getString(0);
         address = cur.getString(1);
         liste.add(name+"  "+address);
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(list.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liste);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    sh.close();



    // On Long Click Listener for Paired BLE Device List
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SelectedDeviceName = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            String[] splitString = SelectedDeviceName.split("  ");
            Devicename = splitString[0];
            Deviceaddress = splitString[1];

            showRenameOrDeleteDialog();
            return true;

        }
    });

    // On  Click Listener for Paired BLE Device List
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           // scanLeDevice(false);
            SelectedDeviceName = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            String[] splitString = SelectedDeviceName.split("  ");
            Devicename = splitString[0];
            Deviceaddress = splitString[1];
            device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(Deviceaddress);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),device.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), true, gattCallback);
            // uart.registerCallback(main_activity.this);

             uart.connectFirstAvailable();//----->this is where i use the instance to call a method
          }
    });
```

My Other class of which i am creating the instance is below...

```
public class BluetoothLeUart extends BluetoothGattCallback implements BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback {
public String mDeviceAddress = main_activity.device.toString();

private Context context;
private WeakHashMap<Callback, Object> callbacks;
private BluetoothAdapter adapter;
private BluetoothGatt gatt;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic tx;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic rx;
private boolean connectFirst;
private boolean writeInProgress; // Flag to indicate a write is currently in progress

// Device Information state.
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic disManuf;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic disModel;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic disHWRev;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic disSWRev;
private boolean disAvailable;

// Queues for characteristic read (synchronous)
private Queue<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> readQueue;

// Interface for a BluetoothLeUart client to be notified of UART actions.
public interface Callback {
    public void onConnected(BluetoothLeUart uart);
    public void onConnectFailed(BluetoothLeUart uart);
    public void onDisconnected(BluetoothLeUart uart);
    public void onReceive(BluetoothLeUart uart, BluetoothGattCharacteristic rx);
    public void onDeviceFound(BluetoothDevice device);
    public void onDeviceInfoAvailable();
}

public BluetoothLeUart(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.callbacks = new WeakHashMap<Callback, Object>();
    this.adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    this.gatt = null;
    this.tx = null;
    this.rx = null;
    this.disManuf = null;
    this.disModel = null;
    this.disHWRev = null;
    this.disSWRev = null;
    this.disAvailable = false;
    this.connectFirst = false;
    this.writeInProgress = false;
    this.readQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();
}

// Return instance of BluetoothGatt.
public BluetoothGatt getGatt() {
    return gatt;
}






// Disconnect to a device if currently connected.
public void disconnect() {
    if (gatt != null) {
        gatt.disconnect();
    }
    gatt = null;
    tx = null;
    rx = null;
}

// Stop any in progress UART device scan.
public void stopScan() {
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.stopLeScan(this);
    }
}

// Start scanning for BLE UART devices.  Registered callback's onDeviceFound method will be called
// when devices are found during scanning.
public void startScan() {
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.startLeScan(this);
    }
}

// Connect to the first available UART device.
public void connectFirstAvailable() {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Entered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Disconnect to any connected device.
    disconnect();
    // Stop any in progress device scan.
    stopScan();
    // Start scan and connect to first available device.
    connectFirst = true;
    startScan();
}
```

I have tried creating instance in different ways like

```
BluetoothLeUart uart = new BluetoothLeUart(this);//app crashes
BluetoothLeUart uart = new BluetoothLeUart(getApplicationContext);//app crashes
BluetoothLeUart uart = new BluetoothLeUart();//app crashes
```

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by 'app crashes'. Do you see an error somewhere? Are the symptoms the same for all three attempts? I suspect the third gives you a compilation error, no? I'd suggest you read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page in the Help Centre, and then edit your question, if you want to get useful answers.

Comment: can we see the log cat output when app cashes

Comment: since this a Bluetooth low energy related application it doesnot run on my pc. the apk should be installed in mobile and tested.

Comment: yes DaveyDaveDave you are correct the third gives compilation error if i donot remove the context parameter from the constructor in BluetoothLeUart.

Comment: anybody any suggetions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BluetoothLeUart,

```
public String mDeviceAddress = main_activity.device.toString();
```

will fail (it will be NULL) because you are creating the uart object during creation of main_activity.

```
BluetoothLeUart uart = new BluetoothLeUart(this);//this is where i am creating the instance
```

IE, you are attempting to initialize objects that depend on each other being fully initialized. There may be more errors; I only looked til I found one.

Comment: thank you brother this really worked. the application stopped crashing once i removed public String mDeviceAddress = main_activity.device.toString(); in BluetoothLeUart. now how do i get the value of mDeviceAddress from main_activity??

Answer (score 0):

you need to create instance in some method then only `this` will be effective, your code should be

```
BluetoothLeUart uart;
```

and initialize it in `onCreate()`

```
uart = new BluetoothLeUart(this);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i have created an instance of another class in same place which works perfectly fine. SqlHandler sh = new SqlHandler(this); please see in the code.

Comment: strange, post your logcat

Comment: tried creating instance in onCreate() still same error.Application crashes.

Comment: this is actually a Bluetooth low energy application which doesnot run on my pc everytime i need to create an apk and install in mobile and see the results.

Comment: but i am pretty sure the error is in that particular line because if i remove that line my application works as expected.

Comment: you are removing that line means you are not using that class anymore, its not necessary that error is in that line only, error might be in your class also

Comment: agreed but what can be the error in that class when my app crashes in beginning itself.i am calling the instance on click of list item.but here the application does not even display the list. if i remove the line i can see the list view and on its click the application crashes.